# text not staying in div

Tags: html, css

I have a few blocks of text that doesn't stay inside of the parent of even the page div. I'm attempting to have a block of text over an image but it acts as if it isn't attached to the image at all. setting the images to position: absolute;
and the text position: relative; seems to break the entire layout.

[as seen in this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9ILt.jpg)

HTML

```
      <section id="productInfo">
        <section class="productDescLargeLeft">
            <img src="images/combat_image1.jpg" alt="combat image" width="410" height="300">
            <p><span>Experience the combat of an MMO, with an oldschool Final Fantasy twist.</span></p>
        </section><!--end productDesc1-->
        <section class="productDescLargeRight">
            <img src="images/craft_image1.jpg" alt="craft image" width="410" height="300">
            <p><span>Use life skills to gather raw materials and create a variety of items...</span></p>
        </section><!--end productDesc4-->
    </section><!--end productInfo-->
```

CSS

```
.productDescLargeLeft {
    float:left;
    width: 410px;
}

.productDescLargeLeft p {
    background: none;
    bottom: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.productDescLargeRight {
    float:right;
    width: 410px;
}

.productDescLargeRight p {
    background: none;
    bottom: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: did you try setting the span max width to match the width of the image?\

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are missing position: absolute though as you said it was causing the layout to be odd, After testing in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0tcjpbkc/1/ I found that by just setting the max width to on the P element to match the image:

```
.productDescLargeRight p {
    background: none;
    bottom: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    max-width: 410px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Then the text happily sits within the image container, As in the fiddle you'll need to also do the same for the other image container `.productDescLargeLeft p`

Answer (score -1):

Check out this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ashpv5pt/

```
<section id="productInfo">
        <section class="productDescLargeLeft">
            <img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/desktop-year-of-the-tiger-images-wallpaper.jpg" alt="combat image" width="410" height="300">
            <p><span>Experience the combat of an MMO, with an oldschool Final Fantasy twist.</span></p>
        </section><!--end productDesc1-->
        <section class="productDescLargeRight">
            <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" alt="craft image" width="410" height="300">
            <p><span>Use life skills to gather raw materials and create a variety of items...</span></p>
        </section><!--end productDesc4-->
    </section>


.productDescLargeLeft
{
float:left;
width: 410px;
position: relative;
}
.productDescLargeLeft p
{
background: none;
bottom: 120px;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
font-size: 16px;
position: absolute;
color:white;
}
.productDescLargeRight
{
float:right;
width: 410px;
position:relative;
}
.productDescLargeRight p
{
background: none;
bottom: 120px;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
font-size: 16px;
position:absolute;
color:white;
}
```

Comment: your div should have    position:relative;

Comment: and your text should have   position:absolute;

Comment: after that you can control text position using top,left,right and bottom.

Comment: The guys submitting the question quite clearly stated that position: absolute was breaking his layout which means it's likely just adding this rule does nothing to solve his problem.

Comment: he was adding position absolute on the div

Comment: which wouls clearly break the layout but using position relative on the div would not.

Comment: Did you even see my fiddle. You gave my answer negative review dude

Comment: You quite clearly jumped on this without fully reading the question, he's tried position absolute but it causes the layout to be broken.. Please read the question fully before attempting to answer it.

Comment: .productDescLargeLeft
{
float:left;
width: 410px;
position: relative
} You were rushing so fast to enter this you forgot to add a ;

Comment: Also by adding position: relative; to the parent your also bypassing the bottom property he originally set.